# JS Image sorter not working for multiple matching ID elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an image sorter with toggle buttons, but my function is only working for the first image with the ID and not any others.

This is the JS function

```
function kitchen() {
  var x = document.getElementById("kitchen");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Here is the html button

```
<button onclick=kitchen()>Kitchen</button>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/?" id="kitchen">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/?" id="kitchen">
```

I'm expecting it to toggle display block on all images with the id "kitchen" but it is only doing the first image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: Also `document.getElementById` only returns a single element.  As reinforced by the **getElement** part of the method name

Comment: @Taplar then how should I get around this. make it a class?

Comment: `getElementById` returns a single (first) element. Meanwhile `id` must be unique.
Use `class="kitchen"` and `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev hey Alex, I tried that but now it doesn't show any images onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this.

```js
function kitchen() {
  var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("kitchen");
  for (var i = 0, img; img = imgs[i]; ++i) {
    img.style.display = img.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="kitchen()">Kitchen</button>
<img style="display:none" src="https://picsum.photos/200/?" class="kitchen">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/?1" class="kitchen">
```